# Covariance in Kotlin collections

Tags: kotlin, covariance

I basically wanted to ask about two specific types - `MutableList` and `Array`.

Why is this OK:

```
var anyList: List<Any> = mutableListOf<String>("1", "2") //why is MutableList covariant?
var intList: List<Int> = mutableListOf<Int>(1, 2)
anyList = intList //Why is this Ok? Where's covariance in the corresponding declaration sites?
```

Why does `MutableList` allow covariance in its type?
Based on its declaration, there's no `out` modifier in it:

```
public interface MutableList<E> : List<E>, MutableCollection<E>
```

At the same time for `Array` it's different:

```
var anyArray: Array<Any> = arrayOf("1", "2") //why is this is fine if arrayOf returns invariant Array<T>
    var intArray: Array<Int> = arrayOf(1, 2)
    anyArray  = intArray //but this is not(compilation error)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, found an answer to my own question:

The trick is that MutableList inherits regular List:

```
public interface MutableList<E> : List<E>, MutableCollection<E>
```

And regular List interface is covariant in `E`:

```
public interface List<out E> : Collection<E>
```

So, if I change my initial code to:

```
var anyList: MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf<String>("123") //doesn't compile any longer
var intList: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf<Int>(1)
anyList = intList //won't work either
```

**UPDATE**

*As pointed out in the comment*

With Array it's a different thing. It works because I haven't tried to explicitly define the type on the right hand side of the statement and so `Array<Any>` is inferred regardless of the values that I passed as parameters to `arrayOf()`

```
public inline fun <reified @PureReifiable T> arrayOf(vararg elements: T): Array<T>
```

Comment: Your array declaration works not because of reification but because it's inferring the type of `arrayOf()`  from your variable type `Array<Any>`. For instance, `var x: MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf("1", "2")` works fine.